# Load DTD (Document Type Definition) XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I work with XML load. but i have problem with DTD XML Load.

My XML Load code is (in C#) -

```
XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
<soap:Body>
<ProcessTGJob xmlns='http://dpi.careerbuilder.com/WebServices/RealTimeJobPost'>
<Batch>
<Header>
<Field name='CBVendorID' value='ED3H3MG5WM50GQP729GL' />
</Header> 
<Job>                   
<Field name='CBDescription' value='Test Description' />
</Job>
</Batch>
</ProcessTGJob></soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>");

Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
string xmlString = soapEnvelopeXml.InnerXml;
Response.Write(xmlString);
Response.End();
```

when execute code it's always give an error `is an unexpected token.`

I can't understand what is the problem in code. please help me .

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the content-type as text/xml or application/xml;

Comment: Ok, but I have got error on line number 2nd (soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml("my xml string"))

Comment: Thank you. but i already tried for this, problem is still there.